# How to calculate exact hours between two datetime fields?

Tags: sql, date, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper, difference

I need to calculate hours between datetime fields and I can achieve it by simply doing

```
select date1,date2,(date1-date2) from table; --This gives answer in DD:HH:MM:SS format
select date1,date2,(trunc(date1)-trunc(date2))*24 --This doesn't take into account the time, it only gives hours between two dates.
```

Is there a way I can find the difference between date times that gives the output in Hours as a number?

Comment: 'datetime' isn't an Oracle data type; are the columns dates or timestamps? From the first code comment I'd guess the latter. Sample data and expected results would be useful though - I'm not quire quite what you mean by 'exact hours' - complete whole hours, or including fractions, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'format' comment on your first query suggests your columns are timestamps, despite the dummy column names, as the result of subtracting two timestamps is an interval. Your second query is implicitly converting both timestamps to dates before subtracting them to get an answer as a number of days - which would be fractional if you weren't truncating them and thus losing the time portion.

You can extract the number of hours from the interval difference, and also 24 * the number of days if you expect it to exceed a day:

```
extract(day from (date1 - date2)) * 24 + extract(hour from (date1 - date2))
```

If you want to include fractional hours then you can extract and manipulate the minutes and seconds too.

You can also explicitly convert to dates, and truncate or floor after manipulation:

```
floor((cast(date1 as date) - cast(date2 as date)) * 24)
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bde8f72649b8269a08c0041af2356ab6)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your solution. For some reason the extract(hour from (date1 - date2)) is always giving me zero. As a result the output is only extract(day from (date1 - date2)) * 24. The date format I see on my data is like: 11-JAN-21 12.23.00.000000000 PM

Comment: Look at the interval given by `date1 - date2` and see how many days and hours that shows. We can't tell much from a single timestamp value. As I said before, adding sample data and expected results to your question would be helpful.

Comment: This solution works. The date field provided by the teams were incorrect. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use the DATEDIFF function in sql.

Example:
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, '2021-09-05 12:00:00', GETDATE());

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use Oracle SQL and Datediff is not a function supported by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it using the differnece of dates and multiplying with 24

```
 select date1
       ,date2
       ,(date1-date2)*24  as diff_in_hrs
  from table
```